# Blender 2.81 - Sculpt level disappeared from Multires modifier

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

I'm using the latest version of Blender: 2.81.
I find it fantastic, but the "Sculpt" level seems to have disappeared from multires modifier.

Currently it is impossible to jump back to a previous subdivision level to do easy smoothing on lower topology levels.

- Is it a known bug?
- Is there a new way to use this modifier?
- Is there a way to get the sculpt level back?

Thanks!

[image: Multires modifier Problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The removal is intentional and temporary to avoid the occurrence of a bug that corrupts mesh data when the multi-resolution modifier is used while sculpting. Once [T58473](https://developer.blender.org/T58473) has been fixed it will likely be available again or an alternative approach will be provided.

Comment: OK. I understand. Thanks for the answer !